Issue fetching Data with Next.js and Cloudflare D1 database
I'm trying to connect a Next.js application to a Cloudflare D1 database.
The database has been successfully created, and the SQL tables are in place.
My goal is to fetch data from the D1 database.
However, I'm encountering the following error when running my function:
What I have tried so far: Checked the database connection:
I verified that the D1 database exists and that the tables have been created successfully.
Checked for variable issues: I ensured that db is properly imported and initialized.
Debugged the error: I checked the console logs, and it seems that db is undefined, which causes the error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'db').
How do I correctly initialize a Cloudflare D1 database connection in a Next.js API route?
export async function GET({ env }: { env: { DB: D1Database } }) {
  try {
    console.log('Checking env.DB:', env.DB); // Prüfen, ob DB korrekt initialisiert ist
    const result = await env.DB.prepare("SELECT * FROM leads").all();
    console.log('SQL result:', result);

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(result.results), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ error: 'Internal Server Error', details: error.message }),
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

